# Load properties File from outside the classpath in a Jar file

Tags: java, properties, jar, classpath

I Have a .jar file which is loading a properties file from his classpath. The .jar file can not be altered or edited but i need to know if there is a way to ignore the properties from the classpath and force it to load another properties file from outside the .jar.

The Jar is being used by an external java web project

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each jar doesn't have its own classpath. Your app has a classpath, and this classpath is the union of `WEB-INF/classes` and all the jars in `WEB-INF/lib`.

The `WEB-INF/classes` directory is usually located before the jars in the classpath (but you need to check that with the container documentation).

So, put the properties you want, in the right package, under `WEB-INF/classes`, and that's the file that should be loaded at runtime.